# Orlicz norms: equivalence and interpretation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normed-spaces, orlicz-spaces

I am studying Orlicz norms and the definition that I know, so far, is the one present in Vershynin's book "High dimensional probability" but I would like to understand if another definition of Orlicz norm is equivalent or related in some sense.
Specifically:

**Def**. A function $\psi: [0, +\infty] \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ is called an Orlicz function if $\psi$ is convex, increasing and such that $\psi(0)=0$, $\psi(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $ x \rightarrow +\infty$ .

Then, Vershynin defines the Orlicz norm as:

**Def**. Given an Orlicz function $\psi$, the Orlicz norm for a random variable is defined as: $\| X \|_{\psi} = \inf \{t>0 : \mathbb{E} \psi\left(\frac{|X|}{t}\right) \leq 1\}$

This definition is clear to me and also how it incorporates subgaussian random variables, exponential, etc.

I have come across another definition of Orlicz norm, though, and I don't understand it they are equivalent or a completely different thing. After some calculation, I would say that they are not, but it seems strange.

The definition is the following:
**Def**. For p>0 define: $\varphi_p(x) = |1+x|^p$. If X is a random variable we define $\phi_p(X) = \mathbb{E}\varphi_p(x)$

**Def**. The Orlicz norm is defined as: $\|X\|_p = \inf \{ t>0: \ln \left(\phi_p\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)\right) \leq p \}$

I have found this definition in a paper by Latala (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-25/issue-3/Estimation-of-moments-of-sums-of-independent-real-random-variables/10.1214/aop/1024404522.full)

Do you have any intuition for what the second definition represents and if they are equivalent to the first one?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Notice that, with Jensen's inequality applied to $-\ln$, we have: $$\ln \left(\phi_p\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)\right) \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\ln\left(\varphi_p\left(\frac{X}{t}\right)\right)\right] = p \mathbb{E}\left[\ln\left|1 + \frac{X}{t}\right|\right]$$ and so I guess the second definition can be seen as a weaker form of the first definition in the case where $\psi(x) := \ln |1 + x|$, in the sense that a non-negative $X$ having a finite Orlicz norm as per the second definition has a finite Orlicz norm for $\psi$ as per the first definition. However that $\psi$ is concave instead of convex.

Comment: I specify non-negative because the article you linked only defines the Orlicz norm for non-negative or symmetric random variables $X$. I'm also not well-versed in Orlicz spaces myself so I will refrain from making a proper answer, but I still wanted to make these comments in case it helped.

Comment: ok this makes sense, although as you point out the function would be concave. 
Also the usual Orlicz functions used for the first definition are of the form $\exp(x^a)-1$: in this collection if you choose $a=2, 1$ there are subgaussian norm, subexponential norm, etc., so still it would be strange to not be able to compare this common random variables.
Maybe I just have to take them as two completely different definitions...